# Ho to determine a check box has been checked and transfer data

Tags: excel, vba

I am new at VBA sorry if this is obvious. I have a program where I would like to check a checkbox, hit submit button I programmed and have the name in the cell to the left of the checkbox be saved and transferred toa different spreadsheet.

I have tried incorporating the code below which can detect checkboxes checked throughout my spreadsheet, but I haven't had any luck modifying to what I need.

```
For Each checkedBox In clrTest.CheckBoxes
    'If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").ControlFormat.Value = xln Then
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = "Would this be a variable?"
Next checkedBox
```

Thank you in advance for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the checked status of the checkboxes, this is the way, you can modify it to suit your other needs.

```
For Each tb In ActiveSheet.Shapes
If tb.Type = msoFormControl Then
            If tb.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then
                If tb.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then MsgBox tb.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
'modify the statements inside the if statement.
            End If
        End If
Next
```